# Can not connect to DB with replica set using docker and nest js

Tags: mongodb, docker, nestjs

I'm working on setting up a replica set for my project using Docker, and everything was going smoothly until I attempted to connect to my database. I'm having trouble figuring out why it's not working. I've tried various combinations, but so far, no luck. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
My docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

networks:
  mongodbnet:

services:
  mongo-service:
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      - MONGODB_DATABASE=${MONGODB_DB_NAME}
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=${MONGO_ROOT_USERNAME}
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    networks:
      - mongodbnet
    command: ["mongod", "--replSet", "rs0"]

  mongodb1:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: booko_mongo1
    ports:
      - "27018:27017"
    command: ["mongod", "--replSet", "rs0"]

  mongodb2:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: booko_mongo2
    ports:
      - "27019:27017"
    command: ["mongod", "--replSet", "rs0"]

  mongodb3:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: booko_mongo3
    ports:
      - "27020:27017"
    command: ["mongod", "--replSet", "rs0"]
```

app.modlue.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { UsersModule } from './users/users.module';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { AuthorsModule } from './authors/authors.module';
import { GenresModule } from './genres/genres.module';
import { BooksModule } from './books/books.module';
import { ReviewModule } from './review/review.module';

ConfigModule.forRoot();
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot(
      `mongodb://${process.env.MONGO_ROOT_USERNAME}:${process.env.MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD}@booko_mongo1:27017,booko_mongo2:27017,booko_mongo3:27017/${process.env.MONGODB_DB_NAME}?authSource=admin?replicaSet=rs0`,
    )
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Where is that application running?  When you say "it's not working", what error or other symptom do you get?  `mongo-service` and `mongodb[123]` aren't on the same Docker network and there's potentially some problems with these communicating with each other; the easiest fix would be to delete all of the `networks:` blocks in the entire file.